# How to change color of arrow & done text in iOS through CSS

Tags: css

When I open a website in iOS/Safari browser and open a dropdown, it opens the dropdown in IOS style, and show left-right arrow and a done text on top.

I want to change the "done" text color to red.

Can anyone tell me how to handle this with CSS?

[image]

Comment: You cannot, it's iOS that sets these colors.

Comment: But in some apps, the color of these are changed to grey, so my client wants this to be done...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunetely, Its not possible for now